# "handicapped" in the sense of "being limited"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I was thinking if the word "handicapped" is appropriate here.

> This is a great way to handle things when your team is handicapped to handle only a few types of issues.

I feel it's not okay since it refers to being incapable however on the other hand it doens't actually talk about a person. It refers to a thing.

Comment: The usage is correct. However, the preposition needs to be corrected and the sentence better be: "... when your team is handicapped **by having** only a few types of issues to handle." HTH.

Comment: _Handicapped_ doesn't mean _limited to_, it means _put at a disadvantage_.  It comes from the sporting sense of giving some competitors a handicap to make the competition fairer, such as a horse with a light rider having to carry extra weight.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/handicapped)

***handicapped***

> not able to use part of your body or your mind because it has been damaged or does not work normally. This word is now considered offensive by many people, who prefer to say someone is disabled or has a disability:

I will suggest ***Restricted*** or ***Confined*** in this context.

> **Restricted**
>
> limited, especially by official rules, laws, etc.:
>
> This is a great way to handle things when your team is ***restricted*** to handle only a few types of issues.
>
> **Confined**
>
> to limit an activity, person, or problem in some way:
>
> This is a great way to handle things when your team is ***confined*** to handle only a few types of issues.

Comment: Read more fully from the same page you have cited: "verb (handicaps, handicapping, handicapped) [with object] **1** Act as an impediment to. ‘lack of funding has handicapped the development of research’"

Comment: If people consider handicapped offensive in some contexts (which it appears to be), that's a reason to be wary of using it even in a different context, although obviously it will depend somewhat on the context you're using it in and the nature of your readership.

Comment: @StuartF Likewise, I will choose to avoid using the word ***handicapped*** if there are other alternatives.